# Diffie Hellman key exchange for VM

Tags: java, client-server, virtual-machine, tor, diffie-hellman

Here's a simpler model:

I'm planning to put 3 VM on VirtualBox - Alice, Bob and an intermediate node and implement Diffie Hellman key exchange between the three. Will this work? Is there any better way to do this? I plan to code the entire thing in JAVA.

Previous Question:

I am working on building a smaller version of TOR network in JAVA. In the model, two people Alice and Bob interact with each other, but indirectly through a fixed amount of intermediate nodes(3 for now). The path is pre-defined as of now, but later I wish to make it dynamic.

Can anyone guide me how do I go about it? I want to use Java for its extensive support for networking. Should I use multiple VM's for the Alice, Bob and the three servers? If yes, how will they communicate?

Comment: This is a topic for a long blog post or a chapter in a text book. It's way too broad for Stack Overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (and note "a **specific** programming problem")

Comment: @yshavit : Hi! Thanks for the reply. I was wondering if you could guide me for the start, and tell me what Alice Bob and the intermediate nodes should be- whether VM or something else?
Please guide me, and we can make this post a proper tutorial for the same.

Comment: I would have to think about it a fair amount -- basically come up with a design. And frankly that would take a bit more time than I have for this. :) That's basically the reason that this kind of question is off topic here; the site's format isn't really geared towards it. But assuming this project is for fun/learning, my advice would be: just start with something, _anything_, and don't worry about having to scrap it later and rebuilding big components. Chances are you'll have to do that, but that's just part of the learning process. Sorry I can't give more specifics, and good luck!